# maximo anywhere mobile app device screen timeout

Tags: maximo-anywhere

How can we set device screen timeout in maximo anywhere mobile apps. Please help by providing sample code. Is there any configuration for timeout in seconds to be set for required screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is a device-specific setting, not a Maximo Anywhere setting.

Comment: My question is can we set screen timout so that after say 5seconds if no activity from user side, automatically app logs out and login page is displayed. Is such feature available in maximo anywhere?

Comment: You could write javascript code that did this, and triggered the logout function of the LoginHandler.